# Better performance in VMware Workstation 8?

Tags: performance, vmware-workstation

My laptop has only 4GB RAM and core-i3, so I'm trying to set up my vm to run smoothly with those specs.

Currently, I have the machine using 2 processor cores and 1.5 GB of memory. However, while the mouse moves smoothly and resolution is fine, the OS itself is very slow and running applications or even internet browsing takes awhile. I'm wondering what I could to increase performance (don't care about hindering host performance).

Any suggestions?? I could really use the help, as this will be used for development.

Comment: Thanks, but what with the negative vote?

Comment: @DeCaf, probably simple VMWare configuration questions are better on [su] than [sf].

Answer (score 1):

If your guest OS supports VMWare drivers it is often a good idea to install them. They will be able to use accelerated input and output routines provided by the VMWare virtualization system and bypass layers of hardware emulation inside VMWare. Using the VMWare video, mouse, keyboard, etc. drivers can make all the difference between a system you enjoy using and one that is painful to use.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could try increase RAM dedicated to the VM or increase the process priority.

My experience (very little) with virtual machine shows that its performance stronly depends on HDD performance.